# How to Allow Multiple Exports from a Vue3 Single File Component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules

I'm making a Vue3 Single File Component for a custom list. In my single file component, I want to export the main default Vue component, but also the enum declaring what type of list it is:

child:

```
<template>
  <Listbox>
    <template #header>
      <h5>{{listType}}</h5>
    </template>
  </Listbox>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export enum PagesListType {
  RecentlyCreated = 'Recently Created',
  RecentlyModified = 'Recently Modified',
  Starred = 'Starred'
};

export default {
  props: {
    listType: PagesListType
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pages: [],
      PagesListType
    };
  },
};

</script>
```

The enum only makes sense within the context of this component, so I don't want to put it in some other folder of types. It only relates to the behavior of this list. But when I try to do this in the parent component, it fails:

parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PagesList :listType="PagesListType.RecentlyCreated"></PagesList>
    <PagesList :listType="PagesListType.RecentlyModified"></PagesList>
    <PagesList :listType="PagesListType.Starred"></PagesList>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import PagesList, { PagesListType } from './PagesList.vue';

export default {
  //parent component details
};
</script>
```

When I import the named PagesListType enum, it is just undefined. What do I need to do to export the named enum correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, using a Vue CLI scaffolded project. Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to kinda get this to work by not exporting the enum, but adding it as a property to the exported default component:

child:

```
enum PagesListType {
  RecentlyCreated = 'Recently Created',
  RecentlyModified = 'Recently Modified',
  Starred = 'Starred'
};

export default {
  props: {
    listType: PagesListType
  },
  PagesListType,
  data() {
    return {
      pages: [],
      PagesListType
    };
  },
};
```

parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PagesList :listType="created"></PagesList>
    <PagesList :listType="modified"></PagesList>
    <PagesList :listType="starred"></PagesList>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import PagesList from './PagesList.vue';

export default {
  computed: {
    created() {
      return PagesList.PagesListType.RecentlyCreated;
    },
    modified() {
      return PagesList.PagesListType.RecentlyModified;
    },
    starred() {
      return PagesList.PagesListType.Starred;
    }
  },
//other parent implementation details omitted
};
</script>
```

Comment: u can get enum inside props. its work but you cant access the props inside other levels component. if you wanna access the props everywhere, you can use `provider` and `inject`.

Answer (score 2):

I opine you need to export `enum` into a separate file and import it in different files to use it. Where do you put this file depends on you mainly, how you want to structure your project.

For instance, `types.ts` file in the src folder can define and export the enum like:

```
export enum PagesListType {
  RecentlyCreated = 'Recently Created',
  RecentlyModified = 'Recently Modified',
  Starred = 'Starred'
}
```

you can use the enum anywhere by importing it like:

```
import { PagesListType } from '@/types';
```

you have to use @/ instead of src/. because of the src folder to @ in your TypeScript configuration available in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: That would definitely work, but this enum makes literally no sense outside the context of this child component so it feels unnecessary. I did find a way to get it to work, which I'll add as an answer here. Thanks!